# Reference to undefined identifier bytes.ReplaceAll

Tags: go, replace, slice, replaceall

I am trying to build a simple webserver. I want to replace all `\n` with `<br>`.
I wanted to use `bytes` for this, because my page body is stored as an `[]byte`.

I use `bytes.ReplaceAll()` for this. But it keeps saying that it's a reference to undefined identifier.

Can someone tell me why? I tried the exact same line within an online Compiler and it worked just fine. Do I miss the library?

See my code below:

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "html/template"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "regexp"
)

type Page struct {
    Title string
    Body  []byte
}

func editHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, title string) {
    p, err := loadPage(title)
    if err != nil {
        p = &Page{Title: title}
    }
    // THE LINE THAT CAUSES TROUBLE
    p.Body = bytes.ReplaceAll(p.Body, []byte("\n"), []byte("<br>"))

    renderTemplate(w, "edit", p)
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The [`bytes`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/) package is part of the standard library, so it is unlikely that you don't have it if you have the `go` tool available to you.

But do note that [`bytes.ReplaceAll()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#ReplaceAll) was added in [Go 1.12](https://golang.org/doc/go1.12#bytes), so if you have an older Go SDK, this function will not be available to you.

Execute `go version` to find out. Get the latest Go from the official site: https://golang.org/dl/

Comment: Thanks a lot :)) save my time :)) I updated go version on ubuntu using this solution https://askubuntu.com/a/755392/1047440

Answer (score 0):

Further to icza's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55026692/1084004),

For the benefit of Go versions prior to `1.12`, the following are equivalent:

```
bytes.ReplaceAll(a, b, c)
```

and

```
bytes.Replace(a, b, c, -1)
```

See the implementation of [`ReplaceAll`](https://golang.org/src/bytes/bytes.go?s=21812:21854#L791)